# Referencing Jars

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am learning Java and using IntelliJ IDEA. How can I add a reference to an external jar in my project (like referencing a dll in Visual Studio)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to IDEA documentation, start reading from the following topics:

- [Library](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/library.html)
- [Configuring Project Libraries](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-project-libraries.html)
- [Configuring Module Dependencies and Libraries](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html)

Answer (score 1):

Click on the "Project Structure" button to the right of the wrench (or Ctrl-Alt-Shift-S).

Choose "Libraries" on the left.

Click the plus sign to add a JAR or directory as a library.

Click on "Artifacts" on the left to make sure the library ends up in the right place for your deployment.